# Why is the account same cross different network in metamask?

Tags: metamask

I have installed metamask on chrome browser and I can see there are some networks like `ethereum, Goerli, Rinkeby` etc. I know some of them are test network. When I create an account in one of the network, my account address is no change when I switch to other networks. It seems the account is unique cross all networks. What I don't understand is how this works? Does each network sync between each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of address generation is same as ethereum in all the ethereum compatible chains. So when you create account, metamask uses the same seed phrase to generate the private key and then the private key would generate same address because the process is exactly same.

Address are not something that are spawned out of nowhere, they are already out there, the only difference comes in when you become the controller of the respective private key, and now you can send any transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Metamask uses a hierarchical deterministic (HD) wallet structure that generates accounts and addresses deterministically based on a single seed phrase.  This is why you see the same account address across different networks when you switch between them.